Removing string between two specified strings in Python 3
I am working on an NLP project that requires me to remove computer code from a piece of text. The code is encased between the tags <pre><code> and </code></pre>. Now I could do a simple regex match, but I want to generalize this function so that it can remove text between any two specified strings, even when they are nested.
For example, if I have a string:
string = "<pre><code> Should be deleted <pre><code> also deleted </code></pre> delete this too </code></pre> don't delete <pre><code> delete </code></pre> "

then I am expecting the output to be the string " don't delete ".
If I do re.sub('(<pre><code>)(.*)(</code></pre>)', '', string), it gives me an empty string.
I know how to do this for single characters, like removing string between curly braces. For example, if my string was string = "{ Should be deleted { also deleted } delete this too } don't delete { delete } ", then doing this gives me the desired output:
a = '{'
b = '}'
regexp = a +  '[^' +a + '^' + b + ']*' + b

while a in string or b in string:
  string = re.sub(regexp, '', string)

regexp evaluates to '{[^{^}]*}' here. The while loop is necessary because solutions like re.sub(r'{[^{^}]*}', '', string) doesn't work for nested cases.
I tried to apply the same logic as the single characters case by doing re.sub('(<pre><code>)[^(</code></pre>)^(<pre><code>)](</code></pre>)', '', string)  but it produces the output: "<pre><code> Should be deleted <pre><code> also deleted </code></pre> delete this too </code></pre> don't delete <pre><code> delete </code></pre> " which means nothing is matched.
Edit: I don't know why but StackOverflow is telling me that my question is similar to this question, and I need to edit to not have it removed. My question is about finding patterns between two strings (of more than one character) that are nested. The other question that mine was deemed similar to talks about stopping at first match, which is not related at all.

If the input is HTML or XML you can try an appropriate parser either from the standard library or external library like e. g. Beautifulsoup.

You cannot in general use regex for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

I often encounter the same problem while parsing HTML code.
Here is my solution:
import re
def find_tag_endposition(tag='', content='', begin=None):
    """
    to find the end position of an HTML tag

    :param tag: HTML tag to find. like "<div>"
    :param content: the context where to find the tag.
    :param begin: the start position to find the tag in the content.

    :return: int
    """
    if not tag or not content or content.find(tag) == -1:
        return -1

    _ = re.search(r'<(\w+)', tag, flags=256)
    if not _:
        return -1

    tag_name = _.group(1)
    begin = (content.find(tag) if begin is None else begin) + 1

    count = 0
    content = content[begin:]

    r = re.search(r'^[^>]*\/\s*>', content)
    if r:
        return r.end() + begin

    reg = re.compile(r'<\s*(\/?)\s*' + tag_name + r'[^>]*>')

    for r in reg.finditer(content):
        if not r.group(1):
            count += 1
        else:
            count -= 1

        if count == -1:
            return r.start() + begin + len(r.group(0))
    else:
        return -1
    
    
string = "<pre><code> Should be deleted <pre><code> also deleted </code></pre> delete this too </code></pre> don't delete <pre><code> delete </code></pre> "
regex = re.compile(r'<(code|pre)')
r = re.search(regex, string)
while r:
    start = r.start()
    end = find_tag_endposition(r[0], string)
    if end > start:
        string = string[:start] + string[end:]
        r = re.search(regex, string)
    else:
        break
print(string)

